# Cannot set quota for user - numerical result out of range

Tags: 14.04, quota

When running following command:

```
setquota -ua username 4718592 5242880 0 0
```

I get this error:

```
setquota: Cannot set quota for user 1002 from kernel on /dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root: Numerical result out of range
```

The command is called by a script on a webserver, which manages the users (websites). This system has been used for the last year without any problems. There are 183 users, which have set quotas (15gb each). I was thinking that the cause might were the sum of the quotas that exceeded the space on the disk, but its around 240gb, so the problem should have started at a lower usercount.

I have tried to set quotas on one of the users to just a little more space than he's using atm, but I got the same error.

What to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an antediluvian question but I stumbled on the same problem recently and here is the solution that worked for me.
For large quotas (for me >4Tb) one needs to use the 64 bits format of quotas **vfsv1**:

In `/etc/fstab` after "defaults" or whatever options you already set, insert:
`grpjquota=quota.group,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv1`

Then:
`$ sudo mount -o remount /home`
`$ quotacheck -cug -F vfsv1 /home`